# R knitr Add linebreak in table header kable()

Tags: html, r, knitr

I am using knitr to generate some reports. I use kable to generate an HTML table in the document. In the headers I want to use linebreaks (or other html tags) to enhance the table

```
<!--begin.rcode results='asis'
s <- rbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))
kable(s, col.names=c("Try Newline\nn","Try HTML break<br>%","Past 6 months\nn","\n%"))
end.rcode-->
```

As you can see I am trying different options without much success. 
In my result linebreaks (\n) are just translated in a linebreak in the HTML source. 
 tags are translated to HTML special characters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `s`? Please post a reproducible example, so that "we can see" the problem.

Comment: Changed the question so you can see the problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, the [pipe table syntax](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-pipe_tables) does not support line breaks in the cells, so if using `pandoc` to convert markdown to HTML (this is what RStudio uses), then you'd better choose some more feature-rich table syntax, e.g. `multiline` or `grid`. Not sure how to do that with `kable`, but `pander` supports those:

```
> library(pander)
> colnames(s) <- c("Try Newline\nn","Try HTML break<br>%","Past 6 months\nn","\n%")
> pander(s, keep.line.breaks = TRUE)

-------------------------------------------------------
 Try Newline   Try HTML break<br>%   Past 6 months   % 
      n                                    n           
------------- --------------------- --------------- ---
      1                 2                  3         4 

      1                 2                  3         4 

      1                 2                  3         4 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

But this is not enough, as line breaks are automatically removed by `pandoc`, so you have to put hard line-breaks ("a backslash followed by a newline") there based on the [related docs](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-escaped_line_breaks). E.g. the following code converts to HTML as expected:

```
> colnames(s) <- c("Try Newline\\\nn","Try HTML break\\\n%","Past 6 months\\\nn","\\\n%")
> pander(s, keep.line.breaks = TRUE)

-----------------------------------------------------
 Try Newline\   Try HTML break\   Past 6 months\   \ 
      n                %                n          % 
-------------- ----------------- ---------------- ---
      1                2                3          4 

      1                2                3          4 

      1                2                3          4 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: With knitr v1.13 the hard-line breaks work with kable if you specify the output as html: `knitr::kable(s, format = "html")`

Comment: Great. Is there a way to make this work when `format = "latex"`?

Comment: @ben Yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to limit column width which you could use to help achieve this in kable. use `column_spec()` where you can specify which columns, and the width in different units like cm,in,em.

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that kable converts the <> to HTML equivalents, i.e. `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"`, so I have a quick fix that will work as long as you don't actually require the <> anywhere else. This has allowed me to get a line break in the column headings in my table.

Essentially once your table is complete just substitute the `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"` in the HTML for < and > and then save it as HTML file. Like so:

```
tbl_output <- gsub("&lt;", "<", tbl_output)
tbl_output <- gsub("&gt;", ">", tbl_output)

write(tbl_output, "TableOutput.html")
```

where tbl_output is the output from kable.

Alternatively, and in particular if you need to use <> elsewhere in your table, you could create your own string for a newline and then gsub it for `<br>` at the end.

Comment: that's neat. Why not for example using <br> because it's familiar and then `gsub("&lt;br&gt;", "<br>", tbl_output)`

Answer (score 1):

With latex output, you can use the [makecell](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) LaTeX package, together with `escape=FALSE`.

`escape=FALSE` will prevent `\\` to be substituted with `\textbackslash{}` in the intermediate LaTeX output.

Here is a MWE:

````
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{makecell}
output: beamer_presentation
---

# Ch 1

## Ch 1.1

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
s <- rbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))
cnames <- c("\\makecell[ct]{Distance\\\\km}",
                     "\\makecell[ct]{Power\\\\W}",
                     "\\makecell[ct]{Energy\\\\J}",
                     "\\makecell[ct]{Pressure\\\\Pa}")
kable(s, col.names=cnames, escape=FALSE)
````

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `column_spec(1:4, width="3cm")` to limit the width, which adds linebreaks automatically. It affects the entire column unfortunately, but works on `format=latex` and `escape=T`